# Calculating the Mode for Nominal as well as Continuous variables in [R]

Tags: r

Can anyone help me with this?

If I run:

```
> mode(iris$Species)
[1] "numeric"
> mode(iris$Sepal.Width)
[1] "numeric"
```

Then I get `"numeric"` as answer

Cheers

M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see `?mode` : `mode` is giving you the storage mode. If you want the value with the maximum count, then use table.

```
> Sample <- sample(letters[1:5],50,replace=T)
> tmp <- table(Sample)
> tmp
Sample
 a  b  c  d  e 
 9 12  9  7 13 
> tmp[which(tmp==max(tmp))]
 e 
13
```

Please, read the help files if a function is not doing what you think it should.

Some extra explanation :

`max(tmp)` is the maximum of `tmp`

`tmp == max(tmp)` gives a logical vector with a length of tmp, indicating whether a value is equal or not to max(tmp).

`which(tmp == max(tmp))` returns the index of the values in the vector that are `TRUE`. These indices you use to select the value in tmp that is the maximum value.

See the help files `?which`, `?max` and the introductory manuals for R.

Comment: This works great. I'm a novice to R but would like to understand what you've done...would you mind to briefly explain the tmp[which(tmp==max(tmp))]  part??

Answer (score 9):

The function `mode()` is used to find out the *storage* mode of the the object, in this case is is stored as mode `"numeric"`. This function is not used to find the most "frequent" observed value in a data set, i.e. it is not used to find the statistical mode. See `?mode` for more on what this function does in R and why it isn't useful for your problem.

For discrete data, the mode is the most frequent observed value among the set:

```
> set.seed(1) ## reproducible example
> dat <- sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE) ## dummy data
> (tab <- table(dat)) ## tabulate the frequencies
dat
 1  2  3  4  5 
13 25 19 26 17 
> which.max(tab) ## which is the mode?
4 
4 
> tab[which.max(tab)] ## what is the frequency of the mode?
 4 
26
```

For continuous data, the mode is the value of the data at which the probability density function (PDF) reaches a maximum. As your data are generally a sample from some continuous probability distribution, we don't know the PDF but we can estimate it through a histogram or better through a kernel density estimate.

Returning to the iris data, here is an example of determining the mode from continuous data:

```
> sepalwd <- with(iris, density(Sepal.Width)) ## kernel density estimate
> plot(sepalwd)
> str(sepalwd)
List of 7
 $ x        : num [1:512] 1.63 1.64 1.64 1.65 1.65 ...
 $ y        : num [1:512] 0.000244 0.000283 0.000329 0.000379 0.000436 ...
 $ bw       : num 0.123
 $ n        : int 150
 $ call     : language density.default(x = Sepal.Width)
 $ data.name: chr "Sepal.Width"
 $ has.na   : logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "density"
> with(sepalwd, which.max(y)) ## which value has maximal density?
[1] 224
> with(sepalwd, x[which.max(y)]) ## use the above to find the mode
[1] 3.000314
```

See `?density` for more info. By default, `density()` evaluates the kernel density estimate at `n = 512` equally spaced locations. If this is too crude for you, increase the number of locations evaluated and returned:

```
> sepalwd2 <- with(iris, density(Sepal.Width, n = 2048))
> with(sepalwd, x[which.max(y)])
[1] 3.000314
```

In this case it doesn't alter the result.

Comment: Keep in mind tho that `which.max` only returns the first index that has a maximum value. Compare:  `x<-c(1,2,2,1);which.max(x);which(x==max(x))`

Answer (score 0):

See ?mode : mode is giving you the storage mode.

If you want to know the mode of a continuous random variable, I recently released the package [ModEstM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ModEstM/index.html). In addition to the method proposed by Gavin Simpson, it addresses the case of multimodal variables.
For example, in case you study the sample:

```
> x2 <- c(rbeta(1000, 23, 4), rbeta(1000, 4, 16))
```

Which is clearly bimodal, you get the answer:

```
> ModEstM::ModEstM(x2)
[[1]]
[1] 0.8634313 0.1752347
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32851846)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).